# Elixir ExUnit: module under test is not available

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I'm following this tutorial: http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/agent.html

So in my Elixir project I have a module `lib/kv/bucket.exs`, and a test for it `test/kv/bucket_test.exs`.

When I'm running mix test, I get the following error: `** (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function KV.Bucket.start_link/0 (module KV.Bucket is not available)` Am I missing something?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So it turns out, the module has to use an `.ex` extension instead of `.exs`, and you need to run `mix compile` to compile the new module. After that, `mix test` is able to find the module and everything works as expected.

Comment: Same error, but my mistake was putting `bucket.ex` in the `test` directory instead of the `kv/lib/kv/` directory (which I had to create).  `$ mix test` will take care of compiling the `lib/` files